# Apache ReverseProxy settings for Portainer

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, docker

I currently have a couple docker containers running on a single node, two of which are an Apache web server that I have configured as a reverse proxy and Portainer which allows me to manage my containers via GUI.

I have tried following this thread: https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/488 but have been unable to forward traffic from Apache to Portainer.

Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /portainer/>
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL someldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName SomeAuthName
require valid-user
</Location>

ProxyPass /portainer/api/websocket/ ws://172.18.0.8:9000/api/websocket/

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would generally not advise adding proxypass directives inside Location but since you have a Location already affecting the same URI, Location is probably overriding ProxyPass, as one is defined in virtualhost context while Location itself is a sub-context in this case of virtualhost, therefore it is overriding virtualhost. So try defining the ProxyPass directive first or, try defining ProxyPass inside the Location like:

```
<Location /portainer/>
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL someldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName SomeAuthName
    require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /portainer/api/websocket/> 
    ProxyPass ws://172.18.0.8:9000/api/websocket/
</Location>
```

The correct order to define Location is more global path first, then specific paths later (with proxypass is exactly the opposite), so you make sure one is not overlapping the other if you define it this way, or like I mentioned before, probably defining proxypass directive above the location one.

Keep in mind you probably have an issue with merging configuration.